# Dovecot 2.2 - can diffie-hellman params file be symlinked to pre-existing one?

Tags: linux, centos, symbolic-link, openssl, dovecot

I'm installing Dovecot 2.2 (limited to 2.2 in CentOS 8), on a VERY lightweight server (1GB RAM, 1 core).  The problem I'm facing is that Dovecot insists on generating its own Diffie-Hellman parameters file at `/var/lib/dovecot/ssl-parameters.dat`.  This results in 100% CPU usage on the machine for a good 20-30+ minutes, rendering it almost unusable.

Earlier on in our bootstrapping of this machine, we generate our own DH params file using `openssl dhparam -dsaparam -out /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem 4096` (using 'dsaparam' option avoids safe primes, greatly reducing time required to generate).

Before enabling the `dovecot` service, could we simply create a symlink from `/var/lib/dovecot/ssl-parameters.dat` -> `/etc/ssl/dhparam.pem` to avoid Dovecot thinking it has to create its own?

Are there any problems/implications that we're not considering here?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell dovecot to use the `dsaparam` option to speed this process up?